# Is developing for Android the same regardless of the device manufacturer for non-lower level programs?

Tags: android

If I have a Samsung, Kindle, or a Goldengulf tablet, is it the same programming paradigm? Do I need something special for one device maker than another - in general? If this is too general, please consider this question,

Can I use Eclipse or other IDE for Android development with the same configuration for Goldengulf (a random Android tablet I saw for low price) and Samsung. I use the Goldengulf as an example because it is very cheaply priced and the Samsung is on the higher end.

This is for in-house applications, if that matters, no app store. No device drivers will written, this is a "standard" application.

[http://www.amazon.com/Goldengulf-ATM7021-Capacitive-Registered-Washington/dp/B00CC8OZ8Q](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CC8OZ8Q)

Comment: Customizations apart (either hardware or software), Android is Android.

Comment: you only have to pay attention to the android version the device has installed. Not all the new features works on older android versions

Comment: @IvanoDonadi So even if it is a Kindle or Samsung, doesn't matter?  Same development process?

Comment: As long as the android version support the feature you want to add it is the same. Programming with android studio will let you choose your target android version and ensure that all the features you add are supported

Comment: @FrankN.Stein does that mean all devices will all a new program to be put on the device?

Comment: ... Uh? well it means that the very same app will run on all the devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The whole concept for developers is to abstract the hardware itself.

The class definitions, the machine itself and all other details should not be altered by the developer a common.

If what you need can be done within the activity/service/broadcast system, then it is likely that a device that is indeed Android will run the same input/output in all of those devices....

That noted, it is possible that a command, a method, or even a whole class to be "loosely" developed in a single device, and thus misbehave in that product.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I could just get a cheapo tablet to practice on then.

Comment: A good "bad product" is good to find bugs, wrong implementations of classes and other stuff that should work, but dont.... As an advice, I suggest buying used phones, then "factory reboot " them, then installing as much `crapware` as possible, so as to check how an average device would work in the field.